# How to init database beans after properties setting?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lazy-initialization, spring-data-cassandra

I have Spring Boot application with two databases: H2 and Cassandra.

After start it has no cassandra properties. Except of cassandra config it has some repositories and services dependent on сassandra. I plane to use them just after I set necessary settings. But spring tries to load all this beans right at the start.

How to load this beans after setting the settings?

Now I have simple cassandra config that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Setter
    private String contactPoints;

    @Setter
    private int port;

    @Setter
    private String keySpace;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keySpace;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cluster.setPort(port);
        return cluster;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give @Lazy annotation on the bean that you want to load after all the bean initialization.

```
@Bean
@Lazy
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
    cluster.setPort(port);
    return cluster;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't help. I think it's because of autowiring. I'll try to add Lazy annotation to constructor with Autowired.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Spring to instantiate this bean after the load of the settings, think in terms of Spring dependencies such as :

```
CassandraClusterFactoryBean requires/depends on CassandraConfig
```

And Spring will take care to creating the beans in the required order.

You could define the cluster bean such as  :

```
@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster(CassandraConfig config) {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();    
    cluster.setContactPoints(config.getContactPoint());
    cluster.setPort(config.getPort());
    return cluster;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's not my situation. Application get settings by TCP client from server after all beans are loaded. Moreover I need to reload been after settings are renewed.